# \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve not working giving me test Test webhook error: 500

Tags: php, wordpress, api, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey
```

This API is working perfectly in the webhook and getting the perfection result. But when I used subcription api:

```
\Stripe\Subscription::retrieve
```

It give me test webhook error: 500.

This is my code:

```
        $stripe_secret_key = '*****'; 
        $dbname="****"; // database name
        $usertable="*****"; // webhook table

        require_once('wp-config.php');
        $connection = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

        mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection);

        require_once('webhook/vendor/autoload.php');

        // Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production

        // See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys

        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe_secret_key);
        // Retrieve the request's body and parse it as JSON

        $input = @file_get_contents("php://input");

        $event_json = json_decode($input);

        $event_type = $event_json->type;
        $chargeId = $event_json->data->object->charge;
        $subcriptionKey = $event_json->data->object->lines->data[0]->id;
        $customerId = $event_json->data->object->customer;
        $amoutDue = $event_json->data->object->amount_due;
        $paidStatus = $event_json->data->object->paid;
        $interval = $event_json->data->object->lines->data[0]->plan->interval_count;

        //insert query
        $sql = "INSERT INTO epti_webhook ".
               "(subscription_id,charge_id, customer_id,event_type, month_interval, paidStatus, data_response) "."VALUES ".
               "('$subcriptionKey','$chargeId','$customerId','$event_type','$interval','$paidStatus','$input')";
        $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $connection );

        if(! $retval ) {
            die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        echo "Entered data successfully\n";

        //count query
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as total from epti_webhook where subscription_id = '".$subcriptionKey."'");
        $data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        echo $data['total'].'===';
        if($data['total'] > '1'){

               //issue is coming here

            $sub = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve("sub_A****");
            $sub->cancel();

        }
        http_response_code(200); // PHP 5.4 or greater`
```

Need help guys. I have updated the latest stripe as well but it give me same error.
Thank you in advance

Comment: I tired with retrive details from customer id and then try to cancel the subscription and it works

Answer (score 0):

`\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey()` simply sets the API key locally -- it does not actually send any request to Stripe's API.

There are many reasons why your code could fail when retrieving the subscription. For instance, if Stripe's API returns an error, this error will be raised as a `\Stripe\Error\...` exception. You should wrap all requests to Stripe's API in a `try/catch` block to properly handle errors.

You can read more about error handling here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#error_handling.